# C++: Display a dynamic array class

Tags: c++, cout, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to print all elements of an array in a class, but do not know where to even start.

Try 1: Cout will not work because this is a class. No definition for cout.
Try 2: Overloading the ostream << operator doesn't seem like it will work because I don't have an index to simply make a for loop for each element. 
Try 3: Is there a way to define a new function similar to the copy constructor that uses an array with indexing?

I am a beginner in C++, so I appreciate any help & explanations.

```
// stack.h -- class definition for the stack array
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <iostream>
using namespace std;

class DoubleStack
{
private:
    // variables: 
    double  *data;      // pointer to the actual array of data 
    size_t  stack_size; // Capacity of stack
    size_t  tos;        // Top of stack. tos==0 ==> empty stack

public:
    DoubleStack(size_t capacity);           // Constructor
    DoubleStack(const DoubleStack& rhs);    // Copy Constructor
    ~DoubleStack(void);                     // Destructor
    DoubleStack& operator=(DoubleStack& rhs); // Assignment operator 
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const DoubleStack& dbl); //Stream insertion operator for Doublestack
};
```

.cpp definitions

```
    #include "dblstk.h"
DoubleStack::DoubleStack(size_t capacity)       // create an empty stack
{
    data = new double[capacity];                
    stack_size = capacity;                      
    tos = 0;                                    
}

DoubleStack::DoubleStack(const DoubleStack& rhs)// copy constructor
{
    data = new double[rhs.stack_size];          
    stack_size = rhs.stack_size;                
    tos = rhs.tos;
    for (int i = 0; i < stack_size; i++)        
    {
        data[i] = rhs.data[i];                  
    };  
}

DoubleStack::~DoubleStack(void)                 // Destructor
{
    delete[] data;
}

DoubleStack& DoubleStack::operator=(DoubleStack& rhs) // Assignment operator
{                                                   
    delete[] data;
    data = new double[rhs.stack_size];
    stack_size = rhs.stack_size;
    tos = rhs.tos;
    for (int i = 0; i < stack_size; i++)        
    {
        data[i] = rhs.data[i];
    };
    return *this;                               
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const DoubleStack& dbl) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i<capacity; i++)
    {
         os << dbl[i];
    } // THIS IS WRONG
    return os;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand the question, but maybe you simply have to change the loop in the `operator <<` to `for (int i=0;i<stack_size;i++) os << dbl.data[i];`

Comment: 1. I know the size of the array as `capacity`; how can I use that in `ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const DoubleStack& rhs)`
2. I know `std:cout` will not work because I tried `cout << s1` , where s1 is a new DoubleStack, and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your loops should all use `tos` as the limit, not `stack_size` or `capacity`.

In the `<<` function you need to access `dbl.tos` and `dbl.data[i]` (unless you add an overloaded `[]` operator to `DoubleStack`). And I added a comma delimiter between the elements of the stack.

```
#include "dblstk.h"
DoubleStack::DoubleStack(size_t capacity)       // create an empty stack
{
    data = new double[capacity];                
    stack_size = capacity;                      
    tos = 0;                                    
}

DoubleStack::DoubleStack(const DoubleStack& rhs)// copy constructor
{
    data = new double[rhs.stack_size];          
    stack_size = rhs.stack_size;                
    tos = rhs.tos;
    for (int i = 0; i < tos; i++)        
    {
        data[i] = rhs.data[i];                  
    };  
}

DoubleStack::~DoubleStack(void)                 // Destructor
{
    delete[] data;
}

DoubleStack& DoubleStack::operator=(DoubleStack& rhs) // Assignment operator
{                                                   
    delete[] data;
    data = new double[rhs.stack_size];
    stack_size = rhs.stack_size;
    tos = rhs.tos;
    for (int i = 0; i < tos; i++)        
    {
        data[i] = rhs.data[i];
    };
    return *this;                               
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const DoubleStack& dbl) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i<dbl.tos; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0) {
            os << ",";
        }
        os << dbl.data[i];
    }
    return os;
}
```